# In android, what "B" (the prefix) in "BBinder" stands for?

Tags: android

Lately, I tried to understand the Binder mechanism in android system, two classes are involved: `BpBinder` and `BBinder`, it seems that `p` in `BpBinder` stands for `proxy`, however, I had no clue about what `B` in `BBinder` stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BpBinder` = Buffered Proxy Binder

`BBinder` = Buffered Binder

*Buffered here related to memory.